# I'm not sure when pre-rendering canvas is appropriate! (my example in description)

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, render

I'm pretty new to HTML5's canvas, and have been reading about pre-rendering canvas images to optimize performance...However, I'm not sure what pre-rendering is actually going to help versus when its just extra code I wouldn't need...

My project requires that I have a canvas, which will contain about 5 images of my web dev projects. These images will be revealed via the scroll distance, and using a wipe effect as shown below.

Would using a 5 off-screen canvas' to pre-load the 5 or so images beforehand be optimal in this case? I think it might be since the effect is dependent on scroll, so the user could repeatedly scroll up and down, and having pre-rendered canvas images may lower the computation required to render and draw the images...

[Wipe Start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W88Lo.jpg)
[Wipe During](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jb1Xu.jpg)

Comment: The base images are static right? These are just bitmaps you got from an image file? Then prerendering would have very little benefit. If you were going to apply a lot of filters to these images, with heavy computations then that would make sense. (VTC as "Primarly Opinion Based" even though "Too Broad" would also fit here.)

Comment: Yeah, the images are just regular PNGs that I assign to Image objects that I draw based on how much the scroll position changed.

Comment: So they are prerendered already. You could do a warming run at page load, drawing them all on the canvas first to be sure they'll get decoded when needed but that's about it.

Comment: sounds good! thanks!